# Get products of an order with Spree API

Tags: api, spree, product

I simply want to get all the orders of my Spree e-commerce system, with all products the user bought in an order. I see I can grab all orders, all shipments, but there is no information about a "complete" query that includes products a user bought.

There is a way to do that ?

Comment: Your query is not clear, can you please explain more of it ?

Comment: If I query /orders/ (which is an endpoint of the spree e-commerce API), I only get the order with e-mail that triggered the order, the status of the shipment, etc. But I do not get any informations about items the user bought in this result.

If I query /shipment with a shipment number, I get all the informations about a shipment, and I get what's in the shipment = what's the user bought from the store. But I do not want a list of shipments because we can have n shipments from one order. 

I simply want a list of orders with all the items the user bought in this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET /api/v1/orders is a paginated query which respons should look something like that:

```
{
"orders": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "number": "R335381310",
    "item_total": "100.0",
    "display_item_total": "$100.00",
    "total": "100.0",
    "display_total": "$100.00",
    "state": "cart",
    "adjustment_total": "-12.0",
    "user_id": null,
    "created_at": "2012-10-24T01:02:25Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-10-24T01:02:25Z",
    "completed_at": null,
    "payment_total": "0.0",
    "shipment_state": null,
    "payment_state": null,
    "email": null,
    "special_instructions": null,
    "total_quantity": 1,
    "token": "abcdef123456",
    "line_items": [
    ],
    "adjustments": [
    ],
    "payments": [
    ],
    "shipments": [
    ]
  }
],
"count": 25,
"pages": 5,
"current_page": 1
}
```

Each Order contains line_items, which are products that you are looking for.

Source: http://guides.spreecommerce.org/api/orders.html

Comment: Even after upgrading Spree gem, I was unable to get this response. Such a weird thing. With a clean install of Spree, I was able to use this API. Thanks !